# How to match identical strings in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Take these two urls:

```
const url1 = '/user/{username}/edit'
const url2 = '/user/harry/edit'
```

Is there a solution to match these two urls and return true as they are similar?

I tried the following and should be the worst solution:

```
const url1 = '/user/{username}/edit'
const url2 = '/user/harry/edit'

const split1 = url1.split('/')
const split2 = url2.split('/')

let matchCount = 0
let notMatchedCount = 0

split1.map(x => {
    if(x === split2[x]) {
        matchCount++
    } else {
        notMatchedCount++
    }
})

if(matchCount > notMatchedCount) {
    console.log('Match Found')
} else {
    console.log('Match not found')
}
```

## **EDIT**

Solution was to use [PathToRegExp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) package! Thanks to @ChiragRavindra!

Comment: Can you define with precision what you mean by "similar"?

Comment: If you define your similarity measure, from there only you can write code that matches for a match.

Comment: `/user/` && `/edit/`

Comment: Similar in word count?

Comment: I think you do not need to split your strings. You can compare with a regular expression. Just google 'compare strings with regular expression'.

Comment: Yup! And these two params (`user` & `edit`) should be matched dynamically.

Comment: Harry and {username} don't look like they match the same criteria...?

Comment: That is a dynamic param. I just want to compare the two ends of string

Comment: So if you want to count `Harry` and `{username}` as similar but also `Sanjay` and `{username}, do you want say that `Harry` and `Sanjay` are similar as well?

Comment: did you checked == 0r === operators

Comment: If your placeholder format isn't fixed, you can use [path-to-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp) which is used by ExpressJS under the hood for URL matching. Only caveat is that you have to specify your route like this `/user/:username/edit` or write a util function to convert your input to the other format. Or, at the very least, it would be a good study to implement what you are trying

Comment: @ChiragRavindra Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to test the url

- `\/user\/` matching `/user/`
- `\w+` matching 1 or more word characters (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]+`)
- `\/edit` matching `/edit`

```js
const url1 = '/user/{username}/edit';
const urlCorrect = '/user/harry/edit';
const urlWrong = '/users/harry/edit';

//generate a regex string by escaping the slashes and changing word between curly brackets with {\w+} 
var regexString = url1.replace(/\{\w+\}/g, '\\w+').replace(/\//g, '\\/');
console.log('generating regex: ' + regexString);
var regex = new RegExp(regexString);

//test using the generated regex
console.log(regex.test(urlCorrect));
console.log(regex.test(urlWrong));
```

Comment: These are the urls that is given by the server. We don't know what the url includes i.e. `user` and `edit`. For eg: we get these two: '/user/harry/edit' && '/user{username}/edit'. The one with curly braces will act as regex. And the regex will test `/user/harry/edit` and returns the result which should be identical.

Comment: Similar to `path-to-regexp` package

Comment: @Sanjay Updated my answer how to generate a regex to test it from the base url.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to look inside this library 
[NPM - String similarity library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-similarity)

Library simply returns the probability of comparing two strings if they're similar.
Then it's all on you to set up the threshold from how many percentages you assume that they're the same.

Comment: This is interesting. Let me have a quick look